# Javascript: How can I find where String.format() is declared in my web application?

Tags: javascript

I have tried in vain to locate where `String.format()` is declared in my web app.  On some pages, it works.  On others, it doesn't.  Sometimes, intellisense will show it even after I've commented out every `.js` reference in the HEAD of my document, but, when I run the page, I get the JS error:

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'format'

I want to know where it is because I want to use it in another one of my pages.  Is there a specific syntax string I can search the entire solution for?

Comment: You're probably looking for String.prototype.format

Comment: @Sacho Can you provide the syntax for that type declaration?  That will at least give me a string to search the solution for.

Comment: That is a string for which you should be able to search. It'll probably be something like `String.prototype.format = function() { ... };`, so search for `String.prototype.format`.

Comment: @ajp15243 That's what I've tried after looking at prototype syntax.  I searched the entire solution for that exact string using no special find options (eg, case match, whole word, etc).

Comment: On the pages where it works type in console `String.format` without brackets in the end. It will print the function's source.

Comment: ...and once you have the source, you can search your app's source code for some unique-looking line in that function source. Of course there are other solutions as mentioned in the answers below...

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: I don't seem to be having luck with the console.  By console, do you mean the immediate or command window?  I typed `String.format` into both exactly like that and all I get is `String.format" is not valid.`

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I am talking about browser web developer console (Ctrl + Shift + J in Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Try in the client code. Open the browser (I prefer IE9+), F12 to open Developer Tools, Script tab and in the right you have a search box.

Type your search criteria there in a page where `format` is already available.

It will open the file and show the code. In the top of the file you can see its url.

[image: F12 tools in IE]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using search, as suggested by others, just set a breakpoint at one of the calls. Then move into the call and voila, you're inside the file where it's defined.

(for example using Google Chrome inspector)

Comment: This is getting me closer.  I set a script breakpoint and stepped into the code.  I entered an .axd file where I see `String.format = function String$format`.  However, I can't seem to locate that declaration anywhere in the solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536%28v=vs.100%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397701%28v=vs.100%29.aspx